# How to diagnose slow USB transfer from embedded linux?

Tags: usb, embedded

I have a board with Cyclone V SE, which contains ARM CortexTM-A9 MPCore (single core). On this board I run linux 4.1.15 built using Buildroot. When testing USB it turned out that while Bulk OUT transfers run at about 20MB/s, Bulk IN transfers run at about 10MB/s. For this measurement I used g_zero on device and a simple libusb based program on host.

The second measurement was done using g_mass_storage on device side and dd on host side. Same results.

Last test was done using a combination of ConfigFS, FunctionFS and my userspace application that read/wrote data from/to RAM. There I got 10MB/s IN, but up to 40MB/s OUT. I expected the speeds to be roughly equal (at least when working with RAM).

I checked the bulk in protocol in [USB in a nutshell](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml) and don't see any obvious reason why IN should be significantly slower than OUT.

Now I know that there are too many things that can cause this and I don't expect a "The slowness is caused by..." answer. But where should I dig and what tools should I use to track it down?

Comment: I'd guess the transfer speeds you're seeing are CPU bound on the ARM device side. You'll probably need to do some heavy profiling to understand where most time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the slower speed is intrinsic to the device you are using.

Assuming that you use an USB dongle (which is what I would use =D), I'd expect that any write to a device would be slower than a read, due to specific needs of any flash device (as far as I know, USB dongles are simply [flash memories](http://media.kingston.com/pdfs/MKF_283.1_Flash_Memory_Guide_US.pdf) with a 'translation hardware' on top of it, making it appear as a simple block device). The device needs to erase whole blocks of memory before it can write even a single bit, hence the slowness. Also, in the specific case of USB flash devices, it seem that [speed varies wildly](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/).

Now, to answer your question: first, I would check the expected write speed for the device I'm using. Second, I would take a look at the processor's user guide and kernel options, checking if there are any DMA options avaliable for USB communication.

Comment: The board I develop itself is a usb device (gadget), which is connected to a PC host. And if I connected a usb host to flash, then reading would be much faster than writing, which is exactly the opposite of my case.

Comment: Could you add some more info to your question? Such as processor family, kernel version, expected USB transfer speed, etc?

Comment: Added family and kernel specs. I expect the IN endpoint speed to be roughly the same as OUT endpoint speed.